# What's the best way to combine these two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Not sure how to explain this clearly

I have two arrays and like this

```
$array1 = array('A1', 'A2', 'A3');
$array2 = array('B1', 'B2', 'B3');
```

I want to create one array by alternating between the 2 arrays.. something like this

```
array('A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2', 'A3', 'B3');
```

Also what would you call this type of sorting?

Comment: `array_merge($array1, $array2);`?

Comment: using array_merge and array_filter will do the trick. array_filter only if you want to weed out duplicates. $newArray = array_filter(array_merge($array1, $array2));

Comment: Are you trying to merge the arrays then sort by the last number?

Comment: I think he is trying to merge 2 arrays into 1 array where the first element would come from the first array, the second element from the second, and so on (alternates between the 2 arrays). But the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$max = max(count($array1), count($array2));
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    if (count($array1) > $i) {
        $result[] = $array1[$i];
    }
    if (count($array2) > $i) {
        $result[] = $array2[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php)

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrays are equal length (`count($array1) == count($array2)`)

```
// Interleave elements from $array1 and $array2 into $result
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    $result[] = $array1[$i];
    $result[] = $array2[$i];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: There not equal length but this is kind of what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard PHP function to do what you are asking.  The closest is:

```
<?php $array_merged = array_merge($array1, $array2, ...); ?>
```

Here is a custom function for you:

```
<?php

        function array_merge_zipped($array_a, $array_b){

            $zipped = array();

            if (is_array($array_a) && is_array($array_b)){

                $a = 0;
                foreach ($array_a as $value){ $zipped[$a] = $value; $a += 2; }

                $b = 1;
                foreach ($array_b as $value){ $zipped[$b] = $value; $b += 2; }

            }

            return $zipped;

        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array('A1', 'A2', 'A3');
$array2 = array('B1', 'B2', 'B3');

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));
$newArray = array();
foreach($mi as $details) {
    $newArray[] = $details[0];
    $newArray[] = $details[1];
}
```